# Strange routing behavior in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, multilingual

In my symfony 2.1.3 project I have a rule:

```
#app\config\routing.yml
acme:
resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing_acme.yml"
prefix:   /

#src\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\config\routing_acme.yml
acme_homepage:
pattern:  /{_locale}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index, _locale:kz }
requirements:
    _locale: kz|ru|en
```

However, working links:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/en
```

Other variatons throw **404 " No route found for "GET /ru/" "** and **404 "No route found for "GET "/kz/"**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself finally, the problem was in missing "/" symbol at the of the rule:

```
pattern:  /{_locale}/
```

However, now this link below doesn't work:

```
http://example.com/
```

I think, redirect to default locale might solve that problem as well, but I think it's quite strange that routes /kz and /ru don't match at all

Answer (score 0):

check out
https://github.com/servergrove/KnowledgeBase/blob/master/src/ServerGrove/KbBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Maybe their implementation helps you